# CSS height issue on Windows Phone IONIC Framework

Tags: css, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework, windows-phone-8.1

My ionic-windows phone App is having problem with CSS height issue. 
I have HTML height set 100 % but on different device the view is going below the screen, It should be within the screen. 
I have to set 90 % and 95 % height for 2 diff devices which is not feasible.
Also, hiding the system tray is not helping me achieve what I want.

Windows phone is rendering Device Pixel instead of CSS pixel. 
The same app is working fine for both android and iOS because Ionic supports them officially.